# Brewing aboard a boat

Tags: fermentation

Are their any sailors here who also Brew beer and wine? That's not really the question though. My question is, under the conditions of a sea going vessel, is it possible to brew beer and wine and what extra steps need to be taken to make it successful?

Comment: It's definitely possible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwPc0JDavaE

Comment: That's actually really cool. A gimbaled system. And making bear with lobster and clams...now that's something else!!!

Comment: @FranklinPCombs that was cool. Wish it showed his fermentor. I dunno about the recipie though lol.

Comment: Is this your take at [programming on a boat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/225745) Stack Exchange meme?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. 
I assume your only real challenge would be movement. If on a large vessel I don't see too much issue, small is a different story.

Just make sure your boil kettles have ample room to not create a splash/spill issue.

Fermentaion may have more challenges, yeast trub may not settle out very well. If there is splashing in the fermenter it may create pressure changes that render a conventional airlock useless.

I would suggest a modified corney keg as fermentor with a 2 bar burp valve, this will naturally carbonate during fermination and be a safe fermentor for the vessel. Use a keg float modification to serve out of the fermentor keg.  Won't be the clearest beer, but if you cold crash you should stall any autolysis while enjoying your beer.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking if the glass carboys could be secured and cushioned properly, that keeping the head space to a minimum (into the neck) would keep the movement to a minimum. I am thinking primary work would be done at dock where their is the least potential for rock and roll, but during secondary and aging, you'd likely be underway at some point.

Comment: @Escoce I wouldn't fill above the shoulder, or you will make a mess and defeat the airlock once it goes off. Using a blow off tube may even create a siphon effect if filled that high. Ideally you only want gases to come in contact with the neck of the carboy. Glass Carboys are not intended for pressure so a burp valve isn't a solution either.

Comment: Not for primary, for secondary and for aging.

Comment: Just secondary. I would totally use a corney keg if there is no secondary additions. First couple pints will have sediment. Imo would be much easier than worrying about glass. Sealed secondary will naturally carbonate too, maybe not to desired co2 volume but still some. Using a float mod pulls beer from the top so there is no sediment until it's spent.

Comment: I would *seriously* reconsider using glass carboys in an unstable environment. People get seriously injured just using them in their basements and garages, I can't imagine how much more risky it would be in a room that randomly moves. I'm not one of the carboy-hating crowd (I've got two I use frequently, never had a problem), but the though of trying to maneuver one of those on a 12m sailboat makes me twitch. Feel free to disregard if you're on a cruise ship or something like that.

Comment: @TMN indeed. Unfortunately, unless you've had one come apart on you personally many think they are indestructible. I personally cringe when I see one setting on concrete, all it takes is a grain of sand in the wrong place.